# Как заставить блок принимать значение высоты другого блока?

Tags: html, css

```css
.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1100px;
}

.left {
    width: 70%;
    margin-right: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.right {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #8c5d79;
    
    display: inline-block;
}

.left + .right {
    min-height: 300px;
}

.statics {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: #89c39b;
}

.statics-circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #8c5d79;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="statics">
                <div class="statics-circle">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            
        </div>
    </div>
```

Есть 2 блока. Зеленый и Фиолетовый. Нужно, чтобы фиолетовый принимал значение высоты зеленого блока. Нужно только HTML и CSS. Без скриптов и флекса. Как сделать?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, Я почитал, что это смежный селектор, но не очень понял, как он работает((

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, фиолетовый блок все равно не хочет принимать высоту зеленого(

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, Прости, забыл указать еще, что без флекса вообще нужно((((

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74155/discussion-between---and-vova-terentev).

Comment: Можно для этого воспользоваться моей библиотечкой [ссылка](https://github.com/xakplant/stickjaw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без флексов ))

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:70% 30%;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.left {
  background: #999;
}

.right {
  background-color: #8c5d79;
}

.statics {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: #89c39b;
}

.statics-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #8c5d79;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="statics">
      <div class="statics-circle">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.content {
  display: table;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.left,
.right {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.left {
  background: #999;
  width: 70%;
}

.right {
  background-color: #8c5d79;
}

.statics {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: #89c39b;
}

.statics-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #8c5d79;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="statics">
      <div class="statics-circle">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: пока я с ним в чате обсуждал , вы уже сделали ... + от меня

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}

.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1100px;
}

.left {
    width: 70%;
    margin-right: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    
}

.right {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #8c5d79;
    
    display: inline-block;
}

.left, .right {
    min-height: 300px;
}

.statics {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #89c39b;
    padding: 25px;
}

.statics-circle {
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #8c5d79;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="statics">
                <div class="statics-circle">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            
        </div>
    </div>
```

у вас стили изначально неправильно определены: без border-box у вас блок распирает отступами и вылезает за края. Если у вас что-то не получается, всегда инспектируйте свой код в браузере(F12) - в вашем случае там отчетливо видно,что блок зеленый вылезает за края родителя, чего быть не должно. Высоты у вас блоки и так одинаковой-это видно в отладчике, либо можете задать элементам border и увидите проблему. Если контент у вас не будет наполняться динамически, и вы знаете что высота блоков меняться не будет,то тогда такое решение подойдет. Если контент будет наполняться динамически - то без JS никак не обойтись

Comment: а если вы щас добавите в левый блок или в правый что не будь ... то противоположный тоже увеличится и станет в высоту таким же ?

Comment: нет, если вы будете увеличивать высоту блока,то тут либо таблица,как в примере выше,либо JS. Но надо понимать,что когда вы используете display: table; display: table-cell; то надо понимать, что и вести себя эти элементы будут как таблица, а не как блоки, что может выйти боком

Comment: такая и была задача ... равномерное увеличение ... в вашем случае это не произойдёт